How to effectively reduce LUKS encryption host disk space
Virtualization platform (arm architecture), deployed a Linux machine, multiple LVM partitions of the Linux machine were LUKS encrypted, I rm
multiple large files on the machine, the machine time space is really reduced, df -h display a total of 2.3G. However, the disk space on the host machine is not reduced, the size is 15G, the format is qcow2, I have done the following attempts, zero fill operation for all partitions, and then rm dropped, Run qemu-img convert -O qcow2 source.qcow2 new.qcow2 on the host, but this does not work, it is still 15G, how to effectively compress the size
I expect the size of qcow2 to be the same as the actual occupied space
